# blender 2.8 UV unwrap distored

Tags: blender, uv-mapping

I'm very new to UV wrapping/unwrapping. However, I do understand the concept. I am trying to create a template to create the image I wish to apply to curved surface on one side of a single object.

However, each time I true to use the Smart UV I get distorted results. I selected faces on the same side of a single curved surface but the UV wrap is more narrow than the object itself. I would expect the opposite.

Thanks!

[image: distorted image]

[image: object in question]

Answer (score 1):

UV Editor shows visual representation of UV islands mapped to particular image aspect ratio. Since you don't have any image, by default, its mapped to 1:1 ratio. Here I have same object UV islands shown on 3 different images and 3 different aspect ratios 512x512(1:1), 512x1024(1:2) and 1024x512(2:1). Same UV islands look too different on different images.

[UV islands on diferent images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82fcw.png)